# How to turn off the Right-Click Context Menu

Tags: c, linux, webkit, gtk3

For a Task I need to do a Simple Webbrowser. The task also says that I should turn the context menu of the Mouse Right-Click off by using the "context-menu" callback.

What I thought doing is:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(-), "context-menu", G_CALLBACK(off_context), NULL);

void off_context(GtkWidget *w, gpointer data) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

But I don't know to which GObject I need to conect it or if this would work.

Comment: [How to turn-off the context menu for the Mouse Right-Click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56548193/608639)

Comment: @jww I saw that but there are no answeres to it and I hoped that someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to disable it in the main Window off your Webbrowswer(Web_View) than just do this:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(web_view), "context-menu", G_CALLBACK(off_context), NULL);
```

In your function you return TRUE which means it can't be void, here you need gboolean:

```
gboolean off_context(GtkWidget *w, gpointer data) {
    return TRUE;
}
```